# When attempting to compile a boost project I get the following error

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to work on a project that uses the boost C++ library. The project in question is

https://gnss-sdr.org/docs/tutorials/monitoring-software-receiver-internal-status/#testing-the-monitoring-client

When I run make in the build directory I get

```
In file included from /Users/me/monitoring-client/main.cc:6:
In file included from /Users/me/monitoring-client/gnss_synchro_udp_source.h:4:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:31:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_iostream.hpp:24:
/opt/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_streambuf.hpp:586:7: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all
      declarations
  int timeout() const
```

the CMake file does ensure that c++11 is the standard and I have not modified anything from the site. I am working on macos Mojave.

How can i resolve this?

```
clang --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: On which OS with which compiler are you trying to build? Which version of boost?

Comment: I just had a look into source of [include/boost/asio/basic_socket_streambuf.hpp](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/5dbdd5c48c6e0fcdb83ac2b5066923b64f5d26a9/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_streambuf.hpp#L579). (Your boost version might be different as I found `int timeout() const` in line 579.) These things are actually looking quite innocent. So, just a shot into blue: There is no conflicting macro `timeout` which confuses the compiler/code? Do you need special settings for your platform?

Comment: ... Concerning the latter, I found a note in [Using Boost.Asio - Dependencies](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html#boost_asio.using.dependencies) although I've no idea how this could be relevant to your issue.

Comment: boost-1.70.0.mojave installed using brew

Comment: That's strange. I switched to tag 1.70.0 in github but `int timeout() const` is still in line 579. (I would've expected that the source code would match your exposed error somehow. Line 586 shows `else if (msec < 0)` which doesn't make any sense concerning the error.) Sorry, no new ideas...

Comment: Try to comment out the entire `timeout` function. It will most likely be needed somewhere else, causing an error there, but what I'd be curious about is if maybe somewhat before `timeout` actually causes the error, which might result in the next function (`connect_to_endpoints`) being "recognized as an error". Other than that, have you tried refactor-renaming `timeout` in order to rule out a macro caused bug?

Comment: I think @Scheff probably got it. There's `#define timeout ...` somewhere that's causing `int timeout() const` to be incomprehensible.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I ever knew that there must be a reason for the convention to write macros in uppercase only (and nothing else)... ;-)

Comment: Please show us a [mcve] (not just a link) that demonstrates the problem.  Perhaps you have some macro defined that's interfering with those headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this kind of problem before.

It was an error in the order in which includes were done.

Actually we used this kind of error on purpose to find the places in the code where we did it wrong.

So, @Scheff is most likely right. There is a #define timeout somewhere which shadows the intended timeout.

And yes, old style macros are evil nowadays when we have C++11, but old style macros in *lowercase* deserve a special place in hell.